# Reverse search & find_next function in Multi_Index container

Tags: c++, search, boost, multi-index

I have a boost multi_index container like this:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    MyData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member<MyData, time_t, &MyData::timestamp> >
        > 
> myContType;

typedef myContType::nth_index<1>::type myContType_by_time;
```

and an search method:

```
unsigned long searchByTimestamp(time_t timestamp) 
{   

    myContType_by_time& idIndex = myCont.get<1>();
    myContType_by_time::iterator itTime = idIndex.find(timestamp);

    if (itTime == idIndex.end())
        return 0;

    // change the index from timestamp to insertionoder(id) 
    myContType::const_iterator itId = myCont.project<0>(itTime);

    return itTime->id; 
}
```

I do the search with timestamp(`get<1> index`) and its worked but it started the search from the first (oldest) data. I want to do it starting from the last added(newest) data according to the insertion order (`get<0> index`). I tried that code but it doesn't worked.

```
myCont.rearrange(get<0>(myCont).rbegin());
```

**1st question:** Is there a way to start the search from the last entered data (according to the INSERTION ORDER not TIMESTAMP I mean get<0> index)

**2nd question:** If the found data is not the one that I want how can I continue searching from the current position/index? I mean is there a method like find_next? (I couldn't find it on docs)

I am working on Visual Studio 2008 with boost version 1.47.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just use `std::find` from `<algorithm>`, together with reverse iterators from the first index:

```
unsigned long searchByTimestamp(Time_t timestamp) 
{   
    auto& idIndex = myCont.get<0>();

    auto itTime = std::find_if(
                idIndex.rbegin(), idIndex.rend(), 
                [=](MyData const& item) { return item.timestamp == timestamp; }
            );

    if (itTime == idIndex.rend())
        return 0;

    return itTime->id; 
}
```

Note: If you want to "project" a reverse iterator to a (forward) iterator, use `.base()` on the reverse iterator.

#### See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6beaaaa08787eb8c)**

---

Now, I don't really know what you needed the *`continue searching from the "current" position`* funcitonality for (I mean, find either returns the match, or `rend()`, so there would be nothing to continue for). However, otherwise, you could do stuff like (see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f780467cdc39f25)** as well :)

```
unsigned long searchByTimestamp(Time_t timestamp) 
{   
    auto& idIndex = myCont.get<0>();

    auto current = std::find_if(idIndex.rbegin(), idIndex.rend(), 
            [=](MyData const& item) { return item.timestamp >= timestamp; });

    if (current != idIndex.rend())
    {
        bool some_extra_condition = current->timestamp == timestamp; // exact match?

        if (some_extra_condition)
            return current->id; // we have an exact match
    } else
    {
        // otherwise look for the next item that has an id divisible by 3 (3,6,9,...)
        auto alternative = std::find_if(current, idIndex.rend(), 
            [=](MyData const& item) { return (item.id % 3) == 0; });

        if (alternative != idIndex.rend())
            return alternative->id;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I made up fully silly examples of 'alternative' matching predicates. As you can see, it's all *run-of-the-mill* STL algorithm usage. This is possible due to algorithms being decoupled from containers by way of iterators.

#### Full Code

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
static int idgen = 0;

enum Time_t { last_month, last_week, yesterday, today, tomorrow };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Time_t tt) {
    switch(tt)
    {
        case last_month: return os << "last_month";
        case last_week:  return os << "last_week";
        case yesterday:  return os << "yesterday";
        case today:      return os << "today";
        case tomorrow:   return os << "tomorrow";
        default: return os << "?";
    };
}

struct MyData
{
    int id = ++idgen;

    MyData(Time_t timestamp) : timestamp(timestamp) {}
    Time_t timestamp;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyData const& md)
    {
        return os << "(id:" << md.id << ", timestamp:" << md.timestamp << ")";
    }
};

typedef multi_index_container<
    MyData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member<MyData, Time_t, &MyData::timestamp> >
        > 
> myContType;

typedef myContType::nth_index<1>::type myContType_by_time;

myContType myCont;

unsigned long searchByTimestamp(Time_t timestamp) 
{   
    auto& idIndex = myCont.get<0>();

    auto itTime = std::find_if(
                idIndex.rbegin(), idIndex.rend(), 
                [=](MyData const& item) { return item.timestamp == timestamp; }
            );

    if (itTime == idIndex.rend())
        return 0;

    return itTime->id; 
} 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    myCont.emplace_back(Time_t(last_week));
    myCont.emplace_back(Time_t(tomorrow));
    myCont.emplace_back(Time_t(last_month));
    myCont.emplace_back(Time_t(yesterday));

    std::cout << "Insertion order:\n";
    for (auto const& item : myCont)
        std::cout << item << "\n";

    std::cout << searchByTimestamp(today)     << "\n";
    std::cout << searchByTimestamp(last_month) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: If VS2008 has trouble with C++11 `auto` usage, find/replace `auto` with `myContType::reverse_iterator` or somesuch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I can not use `auto` since I c++11 is not supported by VS2008. In the sentence `continue searching from the "current"` I mean that; MyData struct has more then 2 values. So when I make a search with timestamp, I also check other properties of the found data. And if they are not ok then I have to keep searching. So instead of starting from the beginning of the container I would like to start from the index of the found data. Hope it is understood :(

Comment: @Vecihi okay, my sample wasn't too far off then

Comment: By the way I just use the `project` to change index. Basicly I'm trying to make the search with the timestamp after founding data I want to iterate over insertion order. So is that a problem for the solution that you offered?

Comment: I'm not sure what you wanted :) However, **[here's a c++03 version of my second example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0329f16dcc38bd81)**. Hope it helps you get started finding your data items :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `upper_bound` more or less like this?

```
unsigned long searchByTimestamp(time_t timestamp) 
{   

    myContType_by_time& idIndex = myCont.get<1>();
    myContType_by_time::iterator itTime = idIndex.upper_bound(timestamp);

    if (itTime == idIndex.end())
        return 0;

    if (itTime != idIndex.begin()){
       myContType_by_time::iterator prev = itTime;
       --prev;
       if(prev->timestamp == timestamp) itTime=prev;
    }

    // change the index from timestamp to insertionoder(id) 
    myContType::const_iterator itId = myCont.project<0>(itTime);

    return itTime->id; 
}
```

Comment: Nope I didn't know that, if I use this instead of using `find` I have to iterate over itenms manually right? Or can I use find in this code as well? I didn't see it in your code? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: `find(k)` returns some element with key `k`, whereas `upper_bound(k)` returns the first element greater than k. If I understand your problem right, the code above should solve it.